# Ни один не правильный

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Привычны сочетания с глаголами, например *ни один не подходит.* А можно спросить

> Ни один пункт не правильный?

Слитное написание тут явно не годится, даже вопроса такого поэтому не ставлю.

Comment: Артем, пожалуй, я отвечу словами Sharon. В разговорный речи такая конструкция вполне правильна. Разговорная речь, вы и сами прекрасно знаете, стремится к лаконизму. Связка "является" более книжная. Часто опускается.

Comment: Можно написать раздельно, если подчеркивается отрицание или из предыдущего контекста ясно, что имеется в виду противопоставление.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж! Понимаете, я чётко виде, что слитное написание относится к одному только, при том что "ни один" затрагивает сразу несколько.

Comment: Артем, да, "ни один" затрагивает несколько. Но при чем тут слитное/раздельное написание?

Comment: При том, что "неправильный" (слитно) относится к одному.

Comment: Артем, у нас формальное согласование. Со словом "пункт". Каждый, взятый по отдельности. По вашей логике должно быть: ни одни пункты (не)правильные. Так вряд ли можно сказать.

Comment: Так, конечно, не скажешь. Дело в другом. Просто с "ни" не бывает отрицательных утверждений (слитного написания), может быть только раздельное отрицание.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Второй ответ

Как я вижу,  дискуссия продолжается,  вот и меня упрекают **в  категоричности**  решения по данному вопросу, который к тому же не был  принят. [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464338/Инфинитив-дополнение-или-часть-сказуемого](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464338/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)

Но Артем очень принципиален в таких случаях, и я это полностью поддерживаю. Если остались сомнения, то принимать ответ не следует.

Поэтому я раскрою подробнее свою **высказанную ранее**  мысль:  «Графический вариант также выглядит странно, неестественно».

Почему же странно?

***Ни один пункт не правильный.***

1. Формально мы видим  классическую конструкцию с отрицанием  (частица НЕ) и усилением отрицания (частица НИ). Так что же тут странного и неестественного?

Но так строятся предложения, в которых **отрицание именно усиливается,** например:  *Это **ни в чем не правильное** суждение предлагается нам как аксиома.* Здесь всё по делу, нет вопросов. Можно также использовать усилительную конструкцию с утверждением: *абсолютно неправильное суждение*.

2. А что у нас? У нас смысл должен быть таким: **все пункты неправильные.**
   Но это не усиление признака (то есть неправильности), а его **распространение** на  ряд предметов: каждый из них неправильный. Но сознание воспринимает оформление предложение как усилительное.
3. Вот и получается **несоответствие**. Мы видим, что при отсутствии усиления предложение оформлено как усилительное. Именно это вызывает интуитивное чувство **дискомфорта** – написание  кажется странным, неестественным.
4. А что меняется, если мы используем связку: *Ни один пункт не будет (не был) правильным.*

Здесь мы уходим от **прямого контакта** двух слов, поэтому больше "не видим" усилительной конструкции. Это такой интересный психологический момент.
Но этот психологический принцип очень важен в языке, его мы применяем при согласовании подлежащего и сказуемого или двух определений при одном подлежащем. Есть даже  такой термин – согласование по смыслу или по форме.

Да вот сейчас на форуме задан подобный вопрос [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464341/в-следующем-объеме-и-последовательности-правильно-ли](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464341/%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8)

Получается, что при соблюдении смысла мы нарушаем форму и наоборот.

5. Но это только на письме, а **в устной речи** отрицание вообще "не слышится" и получается:  *Ни один пункт неправильный*. А это уже нарушение и грамматики, и смысла.
6. **И вывод**. Поэтому "оправдательного приговора" для этой конструкции не будет, а "обвинительную статью" можно, пожалуй, предъявить более серьезную: не разговорность, а речевая ошибка.:))

Comment: Ну вы фантазируете на ровном месте. "Ни один пункт не правильный" = "даже один пункт не правильный". Вот вам и усилительность, она прекрасно сохранилась. "Ни один пункт не был правильный"="Даже один пункт не был правильный" - аналогично. О каких психологических нюансах вы фантазируете, мне не понять. Вот сколько зарекался с вами не беседовать, но постоянно съезжаю в это. Снова последний раз.)

Comment: Спасибо! Про усиление не очень понимаю, что это значит.

Comment: @Артём Луговой Артем, да вы особо не старайтесь, пусть пока непонятно.  Может, потом сами придумаете объяснение.

Comment: @user190920  (1) Что же вы на личности переходите, дорогой товарищ, слово «фантазировать» – это не самый честный прием в ПОЛЕМИКЕ. Признаться, я его иногда употребляю, но только в самых очевидных случаях: когда, к примеру, еще в 2005 году вопрос о связках для СГС (по вузовской программе) был решен, а фантазировать на эту тему люди продолжают до сих пор.  (2) Когда вы перестанете заниматься подстановками – ну, право же,  школьный прием. Говорим о ТОНКИХ материях (о психологии),  а вы предложение меняете. А что этим доказываете?  Все знают, что НИ – усилительная частица, разве в этом дело?

Comment: Я думал, вы объясните, Sharon, что такое усиление. ;) Тогда, глядишь, и ответ приму, если пойму его до конца.

Comment: Артем,  я в  ответе-комментарии снова объясняю смысл усиления, а вы сегодня просто прочитайте. Иногда тему надо оставить в покое, и тогда через некоторое время она вдруг сама понимается. У меня так часто бывает. А за вопрос я вам и так благодарна: пришлось подумать, как бы "ума набралась". Всё какой-то шаг к знаниям.

Answer (score 2):

***Ни один пункт не правильный.***

Я бы не стала так говорить, грамматика **некорректная.**
Предложение может иметь такой вид:  *«Ни один пункт не является правильным».* Здесь всё как надо (отрицание и усиление отрицания), но это книжный вариант.

Конечно, могут быть такие возражения: это  же устная речь, **упрощенная грамматика**. Но в приведенном примере даже смысл настолько искажен, что вас могут просто не понять, дело уже не только в грамматике.

В устной речи мы **не услышим отрицания**, здесь нет возможности для его логического подчеркивания.  Графический вариант также выглядит **странно, неестественно.**

Поэтому **связка нужна,** хотя бы какая-нибудь, например:  *«Ни один пункт не будет правильным».* Можно сказать так:  *«Какие пункты правильные? Правильных здесь вообще нет!»* Это тоже будет усилением отрицания.
Вариантов для выражения заданного смысла много, ваш речевой вариант также подходит.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Какой мой речевой вариант подходит?

Comment: Вы же назвали только один вариант  ( "ни один не подходит"), вроде бы больше нет :)

Comment: Ааа, вы про него! Понятно теперь))

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на комментарий  @user190920

**1. Психология момента**

Вот мы изучаем стилистику речи по Розенталю (или другим способом). Разве мало там говорится о необходимости **сочетания по форме** рядом стоящих слов? Примеры я уже приводила: параллельно идет обсуждение этой темы ("в следующем объеме и последовательности").  Сложно там выбрать: если сочетаем слова по смыслу, то имеем несочетаемость по форме, уж лучше избегать по возможности таких проблем.

Другой пример – это **количественные обороты**. Почему «три больших дуба», но «три большие березы» – неплохо подумать об этом на досуге, здесь тот же вопрос о сочетаемости.

В нашем же  случае проблема  очень просто решается при использовании **связки**. Попробуйте кому-нибудь **иначе доказать**, что «ни  по одному не правильный» – это некорректно.  Вот и орографический редактор недоволен – ни одно написание ему не нравится (нет существительных, согласующихся с прилагательным правильный). Согласился на один вариант: *ни по одному пункту не правильное решение*. Но теперь мне такой ответ  не нравится.

**2. Ну и про усиление еще раз**

Мы привыкли к **стандартным** усилительно-отрицательным конструкциям **для прилагательных**, где в качестве усилителя используются отрицательные местоимения и наречия: никому не известный адрес; ни в чём не повинные люди; нисколько не понятное выражение; ничуть не вредный напиток.

Но у нас нет усиления, здесь вполне **конкретная информация**, например: из пяти названных пунктов  все пять неверные. Какое же это усиление признака (со значением «абсолютно неверные»)? Поэтому вариант **с прилагательным** кажется некорректным, но в то же время мы спокойно относимся к такой формулировке:  *Ни один из пунктов **не является** корректным.* То же сочетание частиц НЕ и НИ, но частица НЕ относится уже **к глаголу**, а не к прилагательному.

**3. Вывод**

Вот такая психология. Здесь нужно очень внимательное и вдумчивое  отношение к языку, а иначе получается такое **быстрое  и поверхностное** суждение:  «О каких психологических нюансах вы фантазируете, мне не понять».

Но читатели, вероятно, уже устали, поэтому на десерт предложу цитату из художественной литературы (в пересказе):

*Попробуйте украсть из зоопарка вещую птицу Гамаюн. На вольере мерцает нестрашный с виду замочек, да только мерцание двойное, а тень он не отбрасывает. Первое искусство – это наблюдать, ему учатся с детства. Нужно часами смотреть на чашку, дерево или камень, чтобы понять, что с ними не так. Не так расползлась трещина, не такой звон, не так падает свет. Камни только притворяются мертвыми и неподвижными, они живут собственной жизнью – тоже движутся, меняются, но только очень медленно.  А если не будешь наблюдательным, то не выживешь.*

Хотя это и фантастика, но очень умная. Вот и **в языке** так же.

Comment: *...но частица НЕ относится уже к глаголу, а не к прилагательному.* Вот-вот, и я это понял, когда писал вопрос.)) Спасибо, всё понял про усиление!

Comment: Артем, у вас прекрасное чувство языка (безо всякой лести говорю)! Мне пришлось основательно подумать над темой, но только когда я УЖЕ написала эти слова и прочитала их (подсказал кто-то наверху, не иначе), я  сама наконец поняла, при чем тут усиление отрицания. До этого и виделось это, но как в тумане.

Comment: Да какое уж там озарение - беспочвенные фантазии (это кстати характеристика не личности, а продукта деятельности личности. Так что никаких переходов на личности нет). Усиляется не признак правильности: "все пункты абсолютно неправильные." Усиляется признак количественности: "абсолютно все пункты не есть правильные." т.е. "и один пункт не есть правильный"

Comment: А давайте без иронии обойдемся. Понимаю ваше раздражение, но вы опять "ведетесь".  А еще говорили "в последний раз". Эх вы, птичка неосторожная!