# Инфинитив дополнение или часть сказуемого?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые

> Мне хочется пить.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, "пить" будет являться дополнением или частью составного глагольного сказуемого?

Comment: Тут однозначно принято считать, что часть СГС. В редких примерах типа "я учусь пить" можно считать дополнением. В чем разница? В том, что "хочу" входит в список СГС-глаголов, а учусь не входит :)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. А где можно ознакомиться с жтим списком?

Comment: В моей подборке, в аналогичном вопросе https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463340

Comment: Спасибо вам большое

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Мне хочется пить.***

**Безличное** предложение. Сказуемое  составное глагольное, оно выражено **безлично-возвратной** формой глагола  «хочется» в качестве вспомогательного глагола и основным глаголом "пить".

***Хочется*** – это именно вспомогательный глагол **с модальным значением**, информацию о тематике вспомогательных глагол можно посмотреть в вузовском учебнике (стр. 69 – 71). [https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)

"Пить"  является **основным глаголом** в составном сказуемом, но не дополнением.

**Составное глагольное сказуемое**

Вспомогательная часть СГС кроме собственно предикативности (времени и наклонения) выражает также различные **фазовые и модальные значения.**

Модальные значения могут выражаться **не только глаголами, но и другими словами** — модальными прилагательными, категорией состояния (предикативными наречиями), наречными и предложно-падежными оборотами {готов, нельзя, в силах и т.п.). Поскольку такие слова не имеют собственных показателей времени и модальности, они употребляются с глаголом-связкой, имеющим в настоящем времени нулевую форму.

**Способы выражения вспомогательной части:** 1) фазовый глагол: начать, перестать, продолжать, стать; 2) **модальный глагол со значением возможности, необходимости, волеизъявления** и т.п.: мочь, хотеть, решить, успеть; 3) глагол со значением эмоциональной оценки действия: любить, бояться, страшиться — или оценки степени обычности: привыкнуть, пристраститься; И т.д.

**2.  Нужно отличать** инфинитив в составе сказуемого от инфинитивов, выполняющих другие синтаксические функции — дополнения, обстоятельства цели, несогласованного
определения.

Объектный инфинитив является **дополнением** и обозначает действие **другого лица, не совпадающего с субъектом действия**, обозначенного глаголом-сказуемым: приказал (X) стрелять (У): приказал X, а стрелять будет У; просил (X) прийти {У-а), велено (Х-ом) разойтись {У-ам) Сравните субъектный инфинитив в составе сказуемого: Решил (X) прийти (X) — X решил и X же придет.

В нашем случае оба действия относятся **к одному лицу** (субъекту действия).
Таким образом, вопрос решается однозначно **по конкретным грамматическим признакам.**

Comment: Выделение первого слова первой фразы, состоящей всего из двух слов, — редчайшее явление. Круто! При общей пёстрой картинке, где каждый абзац обилием выделенного тянет одеяло на себя, важное, переставая быть редким, к концу чтения становится заурядным. А на вспаханном поле естественным образом и прописные идут после тчк/зпт, и не хватает точек, пробелов. Это не важно.

Comment: "Мне хочется питья" - дополнение. "Мне хочется пить" - составное сказуемое. Логики ноль. Городят огород на ровном месте. Субъект действия - это грамматический признак? Грамматический признак - это подлежащее, а оно как известно не равно субъекту действия.

Comment: @user190920 «Мне хочется пить». А что это значит? Это такое внутреннее ощущение: организм испытывает жажду, а конкретики (предмета) пока нет. А что такое дополнение? А это как договоримся. Читайте Кустову (стр.80) Дополнение — это второстепенный член предложения, называющий лицо, предмет или явление, на который распространяется действие или по отношению к которому проявляется признак.   «Что ты мне принес! Мне хочется воды, а не сока».  – «Тогда  так и говори: мне хочется воды».  Конфликтная ситуация, однако.  Поэтому делаем вывод: появляется конкретный предмет – появляется и дополнение».

Comment: Еще раз: "Мне хочется обучения" и "Мне хочется обучаться" это одно и то же. Особенно в свете того, что инфинитив исторически произошел от существительных. И вы не ответили на вопрос про грамматический признак, смешав в кучу грамматику с субъектами действия, вы обосновываете сугубо грамматическую классификацию. Хотя все понятия синтаксиса прямо связаны с семантикой: Дополнение, Обстоятельство итд. Так что этот вопрос, наверное, нужно перефразировать иначе: "Чем меньше классификация завязана на семантику, тем лучше". Моя классификация лучше вашей.

Comment: Ладно,  discussion is over, ввиду взаимного непонимания. Однако, задачка-то СТАНДАРТНАЯ, с готовым грамматическим решением (кстати, для вузов),  которое я просто озвучила, не более того. Так что все вопросы не ко мне, а к отечественным лингвистам. Соответственно,  берите выше, с ними и разбирайтесь. Но вот что хочу заметить: синкретизм  хорош в меру, а здесь УЧЕБНЫЙ ПРОЦЕСС. Вы же ему противодействуете, направляете людей к СОМНИТЕЛЬНЫМ ИСТОЧНИКАМ. Как говорится, обсуждаем  закон до тех пор, пока он не принят, а потом уж извольте исполнять, не так ли?

Comment: Конечно так. Я сразу сказал как принято и сказал, что есть "маргинальное" мнение для кругозора не более того. А вот ваши ответы бывают категоричны и путают людей. Там где министерство официально допускает два варианта - у вас один. Скажем вопрос про не лучший/нелучший или вот недавний непринятый ответ https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464330 (там явно корректно "Ни один пункт не был правильный", но у вас всё "строго". Но там боюсь даже министерство с вами бы не согласилось). Но я что-то увлекся, я ведь не нанимался обучать человека. Кого-то можно пообучать, но корм в коня должен быть...

Comment: Уважаемый (и мне вполне симпатичный) оппонент!  Не многого ли вы требуете от разговорной речи с упрощенной грамматикой  (ни один не правильный)? Министерство такими вопросами не будет заниматься, носители языка сами могут его решить. А насчет нашего участника вы неправы, просто вы людей здесь еще мало знаете и вообще не очень внимательны к ним. Это очень достойный человек, вежливый и вдумчивый, а вы вот некорректно выражаетесь.  Но можете быть спокойным на эту тему – в данном случае «корм будет обязательно в коня», уж поверьте мне на слово.

Comment: @shampar  Вы больше ничего «крутого» не увидели? А жаль. Ничего, что три развернутых ответа за день на самые сложные темы, и все принятые? Мне за просто так очки не дают, везде огромный труд. Но никак не вписываюсь я в вашу благостную картину мира! Нет во мне совершенства, да я и сама это знаю.  Увы, наш мир двухполюсный, и это основа движения, да и жизни как таковой. Но к оформлению надо подходить, конечно, строже. Предлагаю удалять тексты, в которых больше 5 пропущенных пробелов. Внесите в повестку дня и проголосуйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @shampar  А по поводу неправильно выделенных слов могу добавить следующее. Я выделяю опорные слова, важные для понимания смысла текста. Его можно пробежать глазами по этим словам, чтобы понять основную мысль, то есть делается это для удобства прочтения. Если такое выделение не соответствует красивой графике, то красотой придется пожертвовать. Поэтому я оставляю за собой право выделять то, что считаю нужным. Вы уже не один раз делали мне такое замечание, при этом я вежливо вас выслушивала. Но, кажется, пора закрыть эту тему. Если у модераторов есть ко мне замечания, то я их, конечно, рассмотрю.

Comment: «Понять основную мысль» могут многие, и не стоит недооценивать эту способность читающих. Бегать глазами (это такой аттракцион?)  по выделенным фрагментам, т. е. по осколкам фраз, не имеет смысла, они никак не согласуются меж собою, да и не должны; и если видите в тексте хоть одну связь, укажите на неё, а я вместе с благодарными читателями порадуюсь и тему закрою.

Comment: Бегать глазами - это очень удобный аттракцион, если хотите быстро понять, стоит ли вам вообще это читать. Но, согласитесь, у каждого своя психология, что же мы будем  руководить там, где в этом нет необходимости. Поэтому, если позволите, я не буду доказывать. Отмечу только, что так пристрастны вы только ко мне, а ведь у нас много вопросов и ответов с гораздо более серьезными проблемами, чем выделение слов.

Comment: Отсылки к другим проблемам здесь неуместны. Как и переход на личности. К Вам не пристрастен, это выдумка. Пристрастен к правилам и традициям. Они существуют, с ними надо дружить.

Comment: Я все поняла, буду дружить. Все, как вы скажете, извините.