# "в следующем объеме и последовательности" - правильно ли?

Tags: грамматика

Я озадачился. Работы выполняются "в следующем объеме и последовательности:" или "в следующих объеме и последовательности:"? На гугле первое на 2 порядка более популярно, но разум говорит мне, что так нельзя писать.

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что выражение **в следующем объеме и последовательности** закрепилось в технической среде ещё с советских времён, когда оно повсеместно встречалось во многих ГОСТах. Для примера сошлюсь на такие стандарты: ГОСТ 13977-74, ГОСТ 19031-73, ОСТ 1 00559-72, ГОСТ 14803-85, ГОСТ 5961—89. С помощью поисковика можно найти и десятки других. В те времена не зря считалось, что ГОСТы тщательно проверяют профессиональные редакторы и корректоры.

Answer (score 1):

Популярность в гугле может отражать речевые привычки случайных людей или корпоративные жаргонизмы ("а мы всегда так пишем в инструкциях"). Но если искать по *книгам*, то в педагогической литературе (Биология в школе, 1966) можно найти такой пример:

> *Программой предусматривается преподавание четырех предметов в **следующих** объеме и последовательности: ...*

Альтернативный вариант мне в книгах не попался. На мой взгляд, канцелярский характер фразы, направленный на *точность* высказывания, логически влечет за собой грамматическую *строгость* (здесь - множ. число, иначе приходится признать неделимой сущностью "объем и последовательность"), которая в другом контексте могла бы показаться излишней.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Эта фраза у нас часто в договорах стоит. Видно умники составляли их, а последующие поколения пользовались "шапкой".